# Angular material the design is not shown properly

Tags: angular, layout, angular-material

[see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roqeS.png)

Why does the design appear like this? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Add code snippet, we can not get just by looking at screenshot

Comment: It doesn't matter anymore. I solved it. Thank you!